# Advantage of using "x *= -1." over "x *= -1"?

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm looking at some Python numpy code, which contains lines like

```
a = 1. # later on, `a` is multiplied by other floats
x *= -1.
```

(From what I hopefully correctly understand, `1.` is equivalent to `1.0`).

Is there any reason to do this over `a = 1` and `x *= -1`? I can understand it if I'm going to be dividing `a` and `x` by an integer later on, so that I don't have to worry about forgetting to cast them to a float (assuming I want a float returned as a result of the division), but are there other reasons?

For example, if I know that `a` is going to end up as a float, is it better for performance reasons to just initialize it as a float from the start? Or is this just for clarity (to make it explicit that `a` and `x` are both meant to be floats)?

Comment: Probably for both clarity and bug avoidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty much for clarity.

While multiplying a float by an integer may incur a small performance hit (for converting the integer to a float), this depends on the compiler and also shouldn't be a large enough penalty to worry about (unless you are doing *many* such operations).

However, it definitely scores points for clarity. In the end, you really are multiplying a floating-point number by a floating-point number, and there is no reason to hide this fact. If `a` and `x` are meant to be float values, let them be float values.

Answer (score 0):

Any self respecting compiler will promote constants to the appropriate type. The difference is only cosmetic.

Comment: But Python's compilers aren't trying too hard to do anything fancy. And even in quite a few languages that do have clever compilers, the compiler can't change the type of an expression at its whim, especially if it would result in different semantics (as your answer seems to imply) - although it will if the language mandates it, which is an entirely different matter.

Comment: Infact Blindy does not say that the compiler changes the type of an expression but simply that it promotes the constants. I will be surprised if, in Python as in any other language, such conversion pertains to the runtime!

Comment: @eryksyn: you are right! too many years of C programming (and teaching) made me forget about the fact that it make non senso to speak of (static/compile-time) type of vars in Python…

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences in the output that I can detect.

```
>>> float(1.*-5.*0.*-1.).hex()
'0x0.0p+0'
>>> float(1.*-5.*0.*-1).hex()
'0x0.0p+0'
>>> float(1.*5.*0.*-1.).hex()
'-0x0.0p+0'
>>> float(1.*5.*0.*-1).hex()
'-0x0.0p+0'
>>>
```